# Regex doesn't match with parentheses

Tags: php, regex, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I am using Doctrine MongoDB and I have the following code in the query builder:

```
$regexSeller = new Regex('^'.$search['seller'], 'i');
$raw->addOr($builder->matchExpr()->field('seller')->equals($regexSeller));
```

It works and find the good results with a search like this "Bob" but doesn't work when there are parentheses like "Bob (from Chicago)".

I guess the problem is in the first line but can't find a way to match with parentheses too.

Comment: You should probably apply some sort of masking/escaping method to the _data_ you are inserting into a regular expression here. Using PHP preg functionality, that would be the job of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php; check if whatever class is used here has its own dedicated method for that first maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the special characters of your query. E.g. replace `(` with `\(` and `)` with `\)`.

In PHP you can use `preg_quote`(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), like this:

```
$regexSeller = new Regex('^'.preg_quote($search['seller']), 'i');
```

Let me know if it worked! ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, it works perfectly! I hadn't thought of using preg_quote when the Regex was set.